# Linear transformation T such that (<1,1>)=<2,3> and (<1,0>)=<1,1> is?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I have examples of how to compute the matrix for linear transformation.

The linear transformation example is: T such that (<1,1>)=<2,3> and (<1,0>)=<1,1>.

Results in:
\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\1&2\end{bmatrix}

I do not see how to get to that result.

Comment: Note that $T(0,1) = T(1,1) - T(1,0) = (2,3) - (1,1) = (1,2)$.

Comment: The text should probably also say, "in the standard basis".

Answer (score 1):

Using the results of the given transformation, we have:
\begin{align*}
T(<0,1>) &= T(<1,1>-<1,0>) \\
&= T(<1,1>) - T(<1,0>) \qquad (T \text{ is linear})\\
&= <2,3>-<1,1> \qquad (\text{given})\\
&=<1,2>.
\end{align*}
Thus, with respect to the standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^2$, the matrix is:
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 \\1 & 2
\end{pmatrix}